# How To Find Out Server Location For A Given Domain Name

Tags: php, dns, geolocation, whois

Is it possible to find out the server location where domain name is hosted and where the website files is hosted? If we can do this programmatically then that's great. Free APIs also appreciated.

Comment: This just requires two simple steps: Look up the IP address associated with the domain, use any of the myriad geolocation services and/or databases to look up the geolocation of the IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Ping the domain name to get the IP address.

```
% ping www.domain.com
Pinging www.domain.com [65.254.244.180] with 32 bytes of data:
```

Step 2: Query the IP address to geolocation information.

```
http://www.ip2location.com/demo/65.254.244.180
```

Comment: No need to send a ping if you merely need a name lookup: `$ dig www.domain.com`